# How to check whether user has verify the email?

Tags: android, verification, email-verification

I have a problem here. I want to know whether the user has verified the email or not. If the user has verified the email by clicking on the link given, the application should automatically go to the homeScreen. Or else, the user may remain on the same page.

Below is a part of my code:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_email_verification);

    emailVerify = findViewById(R.id.emailVerify);

    final FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    email = intent.getStringExtra("email");
    password = intent.getStringExtra("password");

    emailVerify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            user.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    storeNewUsersData();
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Verification email has been sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Email not sent " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
           
            //check whether the user has verified the email and go to homeScreen
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void verifyEmail() {
    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()) {    //FirbaseUser must not be  null!
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Email has been verified.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Email has not been verified.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wf7DDIaRYjk This tutorial maybe helpful I implemented mine from this.